# Different email list for failure and retries in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Can there be separate email lists in airflow for retries and failures?

I have the below defaults_args:

```
default_args = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'start_date': datetime(2022, 1, 30),
'email': ['noreply@xyz.com'],
'email_on_failure': True,
'email_on_retry': True
}
```

In my case, the failure emails should be sent to emails in `List A` and retry emails should be sent to `List B`.

Would that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `EmailOperator` and both `on_retry_callback`, `on_failure_callback` to achieve that.

```
from airflow.operators.email import EmailOperator


def send_email(to, subject, html_content, **context):
    task = EmailOperator(
        to=to,
        subject=subject,
        html_content=html_content
    )
    task.execute(context)


def send_email_on_retry(**context):
    on_retry_email_list = ["List", "of", "your", "recipients"]
    subject = "subject message",
    html_content = "Body of a message"
    send_email(on_retry_email_list, subject, html_content, **context)


def send_email_on_failure(**context):
    on_failure_email_list = ["List", "of", "your", "recipients"]
    subject = "subject message",
    html_content = "Body of a message"
    send_email(on_failure_email_list, subject, html_content, **context)


default_args = {
    'on_failure_callback': send_email_on_failure,
    'on_retry_callback': send_email_on_retry
}
```